# Get_where() with a clause defined by user

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3

I have an Orders table that I've managed to display, but it takes ~25s to load. When the page loads, I want the table to have ~1000 entries. If the user wants to view older Orders, I will put a dropdown menu. When they select it, it will load the new set.

I tried putting a dropdown menu with the options, but couldn't figure out how to pass that information inside the `get_where` clause.

This is the code where I load the entire entries of the table
`order_id` is the orders id which I want to filter when it loads:

```
$this->db->order_by("order_number", "desc");
$completed_orders = $this->db->get_where('orders' , array('order_status' =>'completed','category' => 'mesoportes'))->result_array();
```

What i'm looking for is something like this

```
$this->db->order_by("order_number", "desc");
$completed_orders = $this->db->get_where('orders' , array('order_status' =>'completed',
'category' => 'mesoportes','order_id >' => $filter))->result_array();
```

where the filter at first run will be 8000 and if the user wants to view older orders then change it by selecting it in a dropdown menu

Comment: It sounds like you want to page the data on dropdown selection, correct?

Comment: yes thats what im looking for

Comment: Please show your relevant controller and view code.

Comment: first, refer to this link [https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results]